# C linked list Process returned 255 (0xFF) execution time 2.144s

Tags: c

I am writing a sequence linked list in C language.

Execution result：  Process returned 255 (0xFF) execution time 2.144s

The struct contains array component and use 'typedef' struct as pointer type, what's wrong with it, can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define OK 1
#define ERROR 0
#define ERROR_EXIT -1
#define MAXSIZE 30

typedef int Status;
typedef int ElemType;
typedef struct
{
    ElemType data[MAXSIZE];
    int len;
}*SQLIST;

Status listInit(SQLIST L)
{

    int len = 10;
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<len;i++)
    {
        L->data[i] = i;  // There is problem here
    }

    L->len = 10;
    return OK;
}

Status listShow(SQLIST L)
{

    return OK;
}

int main()
{
    SQLIST L;
    listInit(L);
    printf("%d\n",L->len);
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: `L` is never allocated.

Comment: You should first define the `struct`. Then define a pointer to it, but it is unwise to `typedef` a pointer, it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: ...and easy to make the mistakes as you just did.

Comment: Minor points a) too many magic numbers, for example `L->len = 10;` should be `L->len = len;` and b) `main` usually returns `0` for OK, yours returns 1. This is at odds with the way `errorlevel` works in a Windows batch file, which allows the batch file to handle various bad exit codes `> 0`.

Comment: @ Weather Vane Thank you for the corrections, I will note that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the struct as:

```
typedef struct
{
    ElemType data[MAXSIZE];
    int len;
} SQLIST, *PSQLIST;
```

Now, you can allocate `L` in `main()` like so:

`PSQLIST L = malloc(sizeof(SQLIST));`

Don't forget to `free(L)` when you're done with it, and rename all your current instances of `SQLIST` to `PSQLIST`.

Comment: C does not have the `new` and `delete` operators.

Comment: Right you are, I've misread the tag. They'd have to use C-style allocation then.

Comment: @WeatherVane To the answer defense, the question had `c++` tag before edit.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the tag deletion.

Comment: In any case, I've gone ahead and updated the answer.